# When changing background-color of html select, first option changes with it

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I'm trying to create an HTML form with several select elements that have colored options for the user to pick colors. I was able to create a proof-of-concept document that successfully changes the background-color attribute of the select to match the background-color of the selected option. However, the first option (which has a value of "none" and thus should have no bg color) also changes along with the select element. I have no clue how to fix this, and it's mildly annoying.

Source code of the proof-of-concept document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <title>Drop Down List Test</title>
  <style>
    select
    {
      border: 2px solid black;
      width: 120px;
      height: 30px;
    }

    select option { height: 30px; }

    [value=none]  { background-color: transparent; }
    [value=red]   { background-color: red  ; }
    [value=green] { background-color: green; }
    [value=blue]  { background-color: blue ; }
  </style>
  <script>
    /*
    This function is called by the onChange event in the form element below
    The only input argument is a DOM reference to the form argument itself

    If the value of the form element is NOT "none",
        Then the background color will be whatever the user selected
    Else, the background color is set to transparent
    */
    function changeSelectBGColor(form_element)
    {
      if(form_element.value != "none")
           form_element.style.backgroundColor = form_element.value;
      else form_element.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <!--
    When the user selects a color value in this drop-down, 
      the background color changes to reflect the user's selection
    The onchange attribute calls the JS function defined above
    -->
    <select onchange="changeSelectBGColor(this)">
      <option value="none" ></option>
      <option value="red"  ></option>
      <option value="green"></option>
      <option value="blue" ></option>
    </select>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Forgive my rather oddly OCD spacing conventions. It's what makes the source more readable & maintainable for me.

Anybody have any ideas on how to make this work? Would like to avoid using jQuery if possible to keep this simple and lightweight, but I'm open to suggestions that use jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the initial colour of the element. Setting the element as transparent pulls from the most recent background-color setting, rather than from an initial setting. For example, set the initial/"none" background-color element to match the actual background-color of the document.